# auth.log indicates error with JSchException?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have a fairly minimal setup server, and it doesn't allow password authentication, only using keys. And it definitely doesn't have Java installed. Normally I don't pay any attention to the thousands of attempts a day of script kiddies to guess my passwords - I figure the time they waste on my system is time they're not wasting on systems that *do* allow password authentication. But I am seeing this message in /var/log/auth.log:

`Dec  7 13:43:43 hostname sshd[7412]: Received disconnect from 189.203.240.57: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]`

Is that mention of what looks like a Java exception coming from the attacker, or is that from something on my side?

Comment: I was also surprised to find a Java classname in my sshd log, on an Ubuntu 14.04 instance on EC2. Is that similar to your environment?

Comment: @AlexNauda Mine is a Linode VPS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like openssh server passes through the last message from the client in its "Received disconnect" error message, so it appears that this is a zombie login attempt from a botnet that is authored in Java.

See this code example from openssh's [`packet.c`](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/tree/packet.c#n1965):

```
            case SSH2_MSG_DISCONNECT:
                if ((r = sshpkt_get_u32(ssh, &reason)) != 0 ||
                    (r = sshpkt_get_string(ssh, &msg, NULL)) != 0)
                    return r;
                /* Ignore normal client exit notifications */
                do_log2(ssh->state->server_side &&
                    reason == SSH2_DISCONNECT_BY_APPLICATION ?
                    SYSLOG_LEVEL_INFO : SYSLOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "Received disconnect from %s: %u: %.400s",
                    ssh_remote_ipaddr(ssh), reason, msg);
                free(msg);
                return SSH_ERR_DISCONNECTED;
```

Comment: "The server passes through a client string" - is this a "safe" thing to do? Or could this be a problem from a [security standpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation#Validation_and_security)?

Comment: If you believe the code in packet.c is vulnerable to some sort of exploit, you might consider reporting that to the openssh maintainers. In general though, I don't think that passing a string through to the logs in this manner presents a security problem.

Comment: I considered that, but I wanted to ask here first, maybe it was obvious from the code snippet that it's indeed "safe". But yeah, I asked about this on [openssh-unix-dev](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2016-September/035373.html "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail") and the OpenSSH maintainer thinks it's not a problem.